# Twitter Streaming API connection working well but getting kicked out after few tweets

Tags: api, twitter, streaming

I have a streaming API script for twitter that pulls tweets and has been working well.  Couple of weeks ago it stopped pulling in data.  So we had to reboot the EC2 server and restart it.  Now the problem is we can connect to the API but after couple of tweets we get disconnected.

Has anyone come across this issues before ?

class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):

```
def getTimestamp(self,created_at):
    '''
    Returns a UNIX TIMESTAMP from a Twitter formatted date.
    '''     
    try:
        stripped = time.strptime(created_at,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
        yy = time.strftime('%Y', stripped)
        mm = time.strftime('%m', stripped)
        dd = time.strftime('%d', stripped)
        h = time.strftime('%H', stripped)
        m = time.strftime('%M', stripped)
        s = time.strftime('%S', stripped)
        return yy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd+" "+h+":"+m+":"+s
    except:
        return False

def on_success(self, data):
    if 'text' in data:
        #print data['user']['screen_name'], self.getTimestamp(data['created_at']), "...",
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `raw_tweet` (`id`,`id_str`,`text`,`screen_name`,`created_at`,`is_stream`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id;',                       
               (data['id'], data['id_str'], data['text'], data['user']['screen_name'], self.getTimestamp(data['created_at']),1))
        db.commit()
        #print "Inserted."       

def on_error(self, status_code, data):
    print status_code
    # Want to stop trying to get data because of the error? Uncomment the next line!
    # self.disconnect()

def on_timeout():
    print "Twitter time-out!"
```

Comment: What happens when it stops? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: No it isn't throwing any exceptions at all which is very interesting.

Comment: Have you read through Twitters docs on rate limiting? Are you ever collecting more than 180 msgs per 15 minutes?

Comment: Yes  I have read it.  I have looked it up and the account hasn't been suspended.  So it can't be that I am hitting the rate limits.  Doesn't twitter provide an email support service at all?

Comment: You get what you pay for :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anyone who starts playing with Twitter's free streaming APIs will eventually have to contend with and design around Twitter's rate limiting behavior. There are things you can do that are less drastic than rebooting your ec2 instance. I'd recommend researching it a bit more.